# Does the category of polynomial endofunctors have a subobject classifier?

Tags: category-theory

Does the category of polynomial endofunctors have a subobject classifier? If not, how can I work around this?

So I believe for the category of presheafs the subobject classifier is something like the functor giving the set of sieves on an object. So if polynomials did have some sort of classifier it ought to be some weird fibery version of sieves. Unfortunately I'm already not too good with sieves.

I'm interested in the subobject classifier because the other way of doing things in terms of subfunctors and monomorphisms directly just gets far too fiddly to mechanize.

I think it's worth noting that I'm actually working with "finitary" polynomial endofunctors for terms in first order logic. So I'm not sure I really need a full subobject classifier for the category of polynomial endofunctors and some weakened variation could probably do.